# Startup program won't launch applications

Tags: python, linux

I'm writing a simple program in Python that launches the programs I'll need for the day and positions them as I desire while I get coffee. Here's an example of a function that launches and positions Chrome.

```
def chrome():
    Popen(['google-chrome'], stdout=os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR), stderr=STDOUT)
    time.sleep(5)
    call(["/usr/bin/wmctrl", "-r", "Chrome", "-e", "0,1356,0,1200,1055"])
```

When I log on, Chrome doesn't open. However, when I run `$ python boot.py` it will open Chrome, wait for 5 seconds then position the window with wmctrl along with the rest of my applications that don't open.

I have the program to start in Startup Applications by setting `python /home/rony/Documents/python/boot.py` and I know it's executing because Skype launches. The only difference between launching the Skype application and Chrome is I use `call('skype')` rather than `Popen()`.

Is there a reason `Popen()` doesn't seem to open my applications on login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned I used `call('skype')` rather than `Popen()`. This was because I could call Skype and the instance wouldn't be tied to the terminal as it would with Chrome and Thunderbird. For some reason on startup whenever an instance of `call()` was executed it would block the rest of the program from executing. This wouldn't occur whenever I ran the program from the terminal.

I thought the problem was `Popen()` not running but it turned out `call()` wouldn't let it. Changing `call('skype')` to `Popen('skype')` has fixed my problems.